# How can I run weka knowledgeflow file (kfml or kf) using command prompt

Tags: command-line-interface, weka

Is there a way to execute the `weka knowledge flow file` (`kf` or `kfml`) from the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

On windows it will be something like this:

```
java -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Weka-3-6\weka.jar" weka.gui.beans.FlowRunner "C:\Users\James\Documents\MATLAB\histdata\workflow2.kfml"
```

(Not sure what this will be on other operating systems but it will be very similar)

If you are trying to automate a process with small changes to the workflow (e.g. input file, output location, parameter change, etc), the kfml file is XML based so it can be manipulated programmatically before executing the workflow (whereas the kf file is binary).